# Maximize the given variable under the following constraint

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the greatest integer $a$ such that $a^5 + 5^5$ is divisible by $a - 5$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a polynomial (euclidean) division of $a^5+5^5$ by $a-5$ : since

$$
a^5+5^5=(a^5-5^5)+2(5^5)=(a-5)(a^4 + 5a^3 + 25a^2 + 125a + 625)+2(5^5)
$$

If $a$ is a solution, then $a-5$ must divide $2(5^5)$. It is then easy to see
that the largest solution is $a=2(5^5)+5=6255$.

Comment: I was going to note that $a-5$ is a factor of $a^5-5^5$ and get essentially the same without doing the explicit division. $a^5+5^5=(a^5-5^5)+6250$